# What is the correct way to code the nested methods?

Tags: c#, silverlight, function

I have created a registration form in silverlight 4, where i have a large number of text-boxes, in front of each text box i have placed a text-block as a required field validator, when any of the textbox left empty while loosing focus, the textblock placed in front of it must become red.

textboxes named textbox1, textbox2 ... and so as the textblocks

the problem is, i do not want code the specific method for each specific textbox, all i want to do is to complete such in just two three methods

here i did some coding which doesn't seems to be correct

```
    private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        if (textbox.Text == "")
           { 
               var textblock = "textblock" +  textBox.Name.Remove(0,7);
               TextblockColorChange(textblock);
           }
    }
    private void TextblockColorChange(object sender)
    {
         var textblock = (TextBlock) sender;
         textblock.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

please suggest some better way to do so..

Comment: dont you need to be looking at dataAnnotation at least to see if this is usable in silverlight

Comment: That would not work. Would it not be better just to change the background colour of the textbox?

Comment: FYI, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this,

XAML part:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
        <TextBox Width="150" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
        <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="#FF0000" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C# Part:

```
        private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;
        if(textbox == null) return;

        var stackPanel = textbox.Parent as StackPanel;
        if(stackPanel == null) return;

        var textBlock = stackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is TextBlock).FirstOrDefault();
        if (textBlock == null) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text)) textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Great job!! thats the exact thing i was looking for..!

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a UserControl that contains the TextBlock and the TextBox and use this UserControl everywhere you currently have the TextBlock and TextBox combination. Then this Usercontrol would have the LostFocus logic inside it and update the TextBlock appropriately. This prevents the need to figure out the right name of the control to update.

Comment: This is the sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I actually prefer Bills approach (although I'd be inclined to use a Templated Control) here is another alternative which is quite fun.  In your xaml use this sort of markup:-

```
 <TextBlock Text="Enter Value 1" Foreground="{Binding Tag, ElementName=textBox1, TargetNullValue=Black}" />
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" LostFocus="txt_LostFocus" />
```

Your common `txt_LostFocus` can look like this:-

```
    private void txt_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = ((TextBox)sender);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
        {
            txt.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            txt.Tag = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the sensible answer, its really very helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

```
var textblock = "textblock" +  textBox.Name.Remove(0,7);
TextblockColorChange(textblock);
```

This code above will just send a string to `TextblockColorChange()`

You don't show any other code, but I'm guessing you want to do a [FindControl](http://abubakar-dar.blogspot.com/2010/09/find-control-inside-silverlight.html) or FindControl like search on that string before passing the result to your code.

Comment: I pointed to a new link that implements a FindControl that will work in the generic case.